# Получение с чужого сайта элемента на PHP

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Приветствую, **Хэшкодеры**.
Помогите в написании скрипта.

**Имеется сайт, на нем есть элемент object.**
`<object id="videoplayer4655" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://site.com/uppod.swf" width="495" height="333">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="movie" value="http://site.com/uppod.swf">
<param name="flashvars" value="comment=filmix&amp;st=http://site.com/styles/video23-1169.txt&amp;file=XRHzQZe3yMzgDWw4BmwsyWYw7C60y07w5mkw20k=f0uYf0QYfxtM5i=w2WEM20D=fW5lDW2Gynpl2T6JXxJgkxkLBmwg5aH3QTYWBR5uBvtuXRHzQZe3yvD8Dxk3yi2gDWw4BmwsyWYw7C60y07w5mkw20k=f0uYf0QYfxtM5i=w2WEM20D=fW5lDW2Gynpl2T6JXxJgkxkLBmwg5aH3QTYWBR5h&amp;vast_preroll=http%3A%2F%2Fads.adfox.ru%2F175105%2FgetCode%3Fp1%3Dbiwlo%26p2%3Demxn%26pfc%3Da%26pfb%3Da%26plp%3Da%26pli%3Da%26pop%3Da%26puid1%3D%26puid2%3D&amp;or_timeout=2"></object>`

Мне нужно реализовать это так, чтобы у меня на сайте появлялся данный плеер, но проблема в том, что сессия потока актуальна только для одного пользователя, т.е. другой пользователь на моем сайте не сможет уже просмотреть видео.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при каждом открытии сайта (моего) - обновлялся код плеера (а именно последнего "value") для каждого пользователя.
Буду рад любой помощи, ибо нужно срочно реализовать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам небольшой пример:

```
    <?php
    //получение страницы (есть более хорошие способы, но этот самый короткий)
    $content = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2GsF1NV9FI');
    //а тут происходит удаление тега <img ... > 
    //можете найти регулярным выражением и заменить нужное вам
    $res = preg_replace('/<img.+>/','',$content);
    print $res;
    ?>
```